# Python модуль вроде как есть но не работает

Tags: python, windows, модули

Захотел попробовать автокликер на python в игре Piano Tiles

По быстрому скачал python и установил модуль

Запускаю файл и пишет что модуль не обнаружен, а в "pip list" он есть

[image: 1]

```
import PyAutoGUI
import time
import keyboard
def click(x,y):
    PyAutoGUI.moveTo(x,y)
    PyAutoGUI.mouseDown()
    time.sleep(0.01) 
    PyAutoGUI.mouseUp()

while keyboard.is_pressed('z') == False:
    if PyAutoGUI.pixel(595,450)[0] == 0:
        click(595,450)
    if PyAutoGUI.pixel(720,450 )[0] == 0:
        click(720,450)
    if PyAutoGUI.pixel(840,450)[0] == 0:
        click(840,450)
    if PyAutoGUI.pixel(960,450)[0] == 0:
        click(960,450)
```

Comment: Я тут попробовал и оказалось что он вобще не видит модулей (PyAutoGUI, time, keyboard).

Comment: Начнём с того, что не `import PyAutoGUI`, а `import pyautogui`